# How to get word which contains number in R with regular expression?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which some of the lines contain the word 'Comments(0)'. I want to get all the occurrences where there is 'Comments' and inside bracket any number.

I am using below code which is giving me integer(0) as  output.

```
text <- c("Because I could not Comments(2) stop for Death - Comments(1)",
      "He kindly stopped for me -",
      "The Carriage held but just Ourselves - Comments(5)",
      "and Immortality")

grep(pattern = "Comments([:digit:])", text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
grep(pattern = "Comments\\(\\d\\)", text)
#output
[1] 1 3
```

or

```
grep(pattern = "Comments\\([[:digit:]]\\)", text)
```

the `(` and `)` need to be escaped since they are regex special characters

`\\d` - digit